# Flutter SingleChildScrollView overrides shadow only on iOs

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

This behaviour is only happening in iOs, in Android it does not happen. When scrolling the view, it overrides the shadow from the component on top and has a weird behaviour. Here is the simplest code I could write to replicate:

```
class ExampleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleView({super.key});


  @override
  State<ExampleView> createState() => _ExampleView();
}

class _ExampleView extends State<ExampleView> {
  var itemsList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
              ),
              color: Colors.yellow,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                  blurRadius: 3,
                  offset: const Offset(
                    0,
                    5,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: itemsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  int maxN = 1 + itemsList.length;
                  double opacity = (maxN - index) / maxN;
                  return Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(opacity),
                    child: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[And here is a GIF showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozMdX.gif)